# how to get table name and a particular column ordinal position in entire database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 9.3 database called `dbSales`, It contains 150 tables most of the tables in `dbSales` have column called `product`.

So my question is How can I get table name and the column- product ordinal position in my `dbSales`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name,column_name,ordinal_position 
FROM   information_schema.columns  
WHERE  table_catalog = 'dbSales' and column_name = 'product'
```

The [information schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/information-schema.html) consists of a set of views that contain information about the objects defined in the current database.