# SQL, using column number instead of column name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to see is there is a way to select a column by their number instead of their name, I have a report that I download from SAP every week that gives me a forecast for the next weeks, as you can see in Column_2 its starts with the current week(week 15), and the next week that I will run the report the Column_2 will change to week16 and so on..

I cannot create a query with the name because every week its changing

SAMPLE:

```
ID  week15 week16 week17  
==  =====  =====  =====   
1    1000  3000   1000
```

Comment: `select *` and process outside of SQL? Or [select from the metadata table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27076378/2908724) and build a query dynamically?

Comment: that is a horrible database design if column names change on a weekly basis.

Comment: What exactly is the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following dynamic query:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT ID ' || ',week' || EXTRACT('week' FROM NOW()) ||  ',week' || EXTRACT('week' FROM NOW()) + 1 || ',week' || EXTRACT('week' FROM NOW()) + 2
' FROM table_name' INTO results
```

Answer (score -1):

If you transpose the table and append it to a rolling table, selecting individual weeks should be trivial.

```
week      ID 
======   =====  
week15    1000
week16    3000
week17    1000
```